Modular Hamiltonian of Thermal States
In this notes in Remark 20 (page 40) the author states that if a density matrix $\rho$ is thermal, then the modular Hamiltonian is just given by the physical Hamiltonian, i.e. modular time evolution is just physical time evolution.
In other references I've seen the statement, that for a thermal state the modular Hamiltonian is given by $\beta$ times the physical Hamiltonian, where $\beta$ is the inverse temperature.
Consider for example the thermofield double state
\begin{align}
\left|TFD\right> = \frac{1}{\sqrt{Z}}\sum_n e^{-\frac{\beta}{2}E_n}\left|n\right>\otimes \left|n\right>
\end{align}
How can I see that the modular Hamiltonian of this state is proportional to the physical Hamiltonian?
